# getting value from drop down list in JSP

Tags: jquery, html, jsp

How can I get a value of a drop down list in JSP and store it through session?

Comment: getParameter should return the selected value. Try it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HTML

Note: note here **name** attribute of combobox is specified

```
   <select name="comboOne" >
      <option>Small0</option>
      <option>Small1</option>
      <option>Small2</option>
   </select>
   <input type="submit"/>

</form>
```

JSP / SERVLET

```
request.getParameter("comboOne");//this will return selected value
```

I would suggest to go for JSTL approch.

Comment: You forgot the option values :) It will always return an empty string this way. Plus, I don't understand the last sentence about JSTL. Also, naming "combo" is a bit misleading since it actually stands for *Editable dropdown*. This one is just a plain dropdown, not a combo(box).

Comment: @BalusC yes  I missed option values but it won't always return emtry string it sill return selected option. about JSTL approch instead using pure java code I suggested OP to go for JSTL approch , and agree with your combobox comment Thanks :)